# Error Installing Whirr using Maven

Tags: maven, hadoop, apache-whirr

When installing Whirr using this command:

mvn clean install

This error occurs:

Failed to execute goal on project whirr-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.whirr:whirr-core:jar:0.1.0+23: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.google.code.guice:guice:jar:2.1-r1201, javax.inject:inject:jar:1.0: Failure to find com.google.code.guice:guice:jar:2.1-r1201 in http://jclouds.googlecode.com/svn/repo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jclouds has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

How may this error be resolved?  Thank you!

Comment: @kleopatra It's not a stacktrace. Those Maven errors are difficult to format, to be fair.

Comment: @DuncanJones ahh ... I didn't notice, too badly form... :-) Thanks for the heads up, should have read more carefully.

Comment: try cleaning your maven repo cache. in your home directory look for .m2 folder and delete cache within it. run again and check.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating with the `-U` flag to force an update. You may have suffered temporary networking issues:

`mvn -U clean install`

If this doesn't work, I have to wonder if you've specified the correct repositories in either your POM or your `settings.xml` file. Maybe Google to see which repositories hold the artifact that Maven can't find?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  No luck.  I will do some searching and advise the results.